# To be able to send BadRequest Object from an extension method with Error Message String

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, extension-methods, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to return a BadRequest IHttpActionResult object from an extension method. However I am unable to use the same.

My requirement is simply return a BadRequest error code along with my string message.

Even If I try to use new BadRequestResult() I am unable to specify the string message that I want it to be send along with 400 error code.

How can I pass string to BadRequestResult ...

In other words, which method or a property I should use with BadRequestResult object that can take my message.

PLEASE SEE: If I don't use an extension method then I can specify my message from apiController directly i.e.

```
IHttActionResult Get() 
{
   return BadRequest("It has not been implemented yet");

}
```

But when I want to do it in an extension method of ApiController type then I don't know any way:

```
  public static string ValidateRequest(this ApiController controller, object request)
            {
                if (request != null && controller.ModelState.IsValid) return null'

// return here..
         }
```

**There is no way I could set object BadRequestResult with < message >!**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you are "unable"? What happens when you try? Your fingers won't type?

Comment: you didn't really clarify the problem... `There is no way...` isn't exactly a call for help, and you never mention if you get an error message, or compiler error, or why this won't work.

Comment: "There is no way I can" means *exactly* the same thing as "I am unable to". Your edit didn't improve anything. Insulting the people who might help you wasn't a great idea either.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That is what I have tried to tell you that you don't need to be insulting me either. If you don't like my medicine then stop giving me the same!

Comment: I think he's saying it's not an available option on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be 100% clear here with what you are trying to do with your Extension Method.  But you are making an extension method that returns a string.  As returning a string, it will never be possible for you to return a BadRequestResult as it isn't a string.

If the question is wanting to specify a custom error message with the BadRequestResult [this is a good example.](http://www.forgetfulcoder.com/2015/02/web-apis-bad-request-with-custom-result.html)